# Acción cuando el test falla, en selenium con java y testNG

Tags: java, selenium, maven, test-ng

tengo un código de prueba donde realiza un AssertEquals del resultado de una operación matemática en la página, https://testsheepnz.github.io/BasicCalculator.html la cosa es que estoy tratando de realizar un screenshot cuando el test falle, exite una manera de que el código realice una acción cuando el test falle o salga exitoso?

public class prueba_screenshot {

```
EdgeDriver driver;
Select operation;
By operationlocator = By.id("selectOperationDropdown");
By number1locator = By.id("number1Field");
By number2locator = By.id("number2Field");
By calculatebuttonlocator = By.id("calculateButton");
By resultlocator = By.id("numberAnswerField");
By screenshotlocator = By.cssSelector("div[class='col-lg-12 text-left']");

String numero1 = "5";
String numero2 = "3";
String result = "";
String resultEsperado = "7";
ITestResult resultadoprueba;
boolean finalmente = true;

@BeforeSuite
public void SetUp() throws InterruptedException {
    driver = new EdgeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://testsheepnz.github.io/BasicCalculator.html");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}

@Test
public void testConScreenshot() throws InterruptedException{

    driver.findElement(number1locator).sendKeys(numero1);
    driver.findElement(number2locator).sendKeys(numero2);
    operation = new Select(driver.findElement(operationlocator));
    operation.selectByValue("0");

    driver.findElement(calculatebuttonlocator).click();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    result = driver.findElement(resultlocator).getAttribute("value");

    Assert.assertEquals(result, resultEsperado);
}

@AfterSuite
public void Teardown(){
    

    driver.close();
}
```

}

Este es la acción que quiero agregar en dado caso que el test testConScreenshot falle

```
   Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);

  ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(), "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\raine\\Desktop\\test\\page(2).jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola te dejo un codigo de ejemplo.

```
    @AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result, ITestContext testContext) {
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)DriverContext.getDriver();
      if (!result.isSuccess()){
            String stackTrace = Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(result.getThrowable());
        
         if (stackTrace.contains("org.testng.Assert.fail")){
                executor.executeScript("lambda-status=failed");

         }else {
                HtmlReport.addWarning("El test fallo inesperadamente.");
                HtmlReport.addWarning("Error info: "+ stackTrace);
                executor.executeScript("lambda-status=failed");
         } 
         HtmlReport.addInfo("Test finalizado con errores!");
      }else {
          executor.executeScript("lambda-status=passed");
          HtmlReport.addInfo("Test finalizado correctamente!");
      } 

      quitDriver();
}
```

en las secciones que falla, puedes colocar que capture una foto, o haga otra cosa como un fail();

Saludos.

Comment: Lo probé usando ItestResult pero pareciera que si uso ese tipo de dato el código no lee o no entra en el @After

Comment: Es que testng tiene diferentes etiquetas dependiendo el uso, algunas son para la suite antes y despues, otras son para los metodos antes y depues, otras son para test antes y depues. Ahí tienes que ir viendo.

Answer (score 0):

```
@After
public void after(Scenario scenario){
    log.info("Finishing scenario: " + scenario.getName());
    if(scenario.isFailed()){
        log.info("Scenario failed, taking screenshot");
        final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        long time = new Date().getTime();
        String outputName = "screenshots_" + scenario.getName() + "_" + time + ".png";
        scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", outputName);

    }
    driver.close();
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.